# loadDataWithBaseURL does not load images which are part of html page

Tags: java, android, image, http, webview

I am battling with this issue for a long time, dug around Google and SO but still no luck. Finally, I am out here to get your help, please advise or help.

My problem with the following source code is that it only displays string content the images do not display instead it shows white rectangle or sometimes a blue image with question mark.

Q: How to display images?

Here is my code:

```
private void openURL() {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new HttpsRequest(getApplicationContext());
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getUrlField().getText().toString());
    // Execute the GET call and obtain the response
    HttpResponse getResponse;
    try {
        getResponse = client.execute(get);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

        String content = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
        getWebView().loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, "text/html", "utf-8",
                null);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        WSLog.e(THIS_FILE, "HTTP Error.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        WSLog.e(THIS_FILE, "Url Load Error.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

webView output:

[image]

Comment: Instead of first `null` in `loadDataWithBaseURL` you have to place there value of `getUrlField().getText().toString()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it does not solve it. I still see the same output.  thanks for advise.

Comment: Do you know the url where images for this page are stored? You have to put that url as a first parameter in `loadDataWithBaseURL`

Comment: I can get the url for this image but this page has more than one image ( how to handle multiple images ?) If I hard code the image url then how would I manage future modification done on the page like change in image name or new image added etc.  There should be some dynamic way to capture these images and display them appropriately.

Comment: If images urls look like `http://mysite.com/image1.jpg` and `http://mysite.com/image2.jpg` then base url for this images is `http://mysite.com/`

Comment: I have added the base url as first param, getting following error. 06-22 15:46:32.611: E/Web Console(916): Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load. at https://mywebsite.com/idVService_ips_1_0/   my base url is https://mywebsite.com/idVService_ips_1_0/ and all images are in images folder. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Vasarat and few modification from my side helped me to answer this question. I have modified the following code line as

```
getWebView().loadDataWithBaseURL("http://mywebSite.com/parent_dir_to_iamges/", content, "text/html", "UTF-8","about:blank");
```

This modification gave me the perfect output as expected.

Please fallow the comments to understand details about the issue.

**Note**: I have used http in the base url instead https.....Please let me know if I can use https.  `webview.Loadurl()` with https url works fine if API level is 10 or above but it shows blank page for API level 8.